# kolla-ansible openstack bootstrap-servers failed on enabling ceph apt repository (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ansible, openstack, ceph, ubuntu-22.04, kolla-ansible

This is to deploy the recent kolla-ansible openstack.  The problem happens since last week.  I retested it on a good environment successfully deployed on 7/14/2023 and got bootstrap-servers failed this time.

The environments use Ubuntu 22.04 and external ceph for cinder and glance backend storage. The error could be due to some recent changes on kolla-ansible openstack, ubuntu, or ceph.  It affects compute nodes only.

Is there any way for a workaround?  I am thinking maybe there is a way to maneuver the repo cache on the ubuntu 22.04 nodes.  Maybe based on the ansible output below, I can get some insight on what exactly that ansible task was doing.  I read the man page of apt-key(8) but have no idea what to act.  I'd appreciate it if someone can teach me some tricks here.

I also need to find the community of kolla-ansible openstack and report the problem there.  I'd appreciate it if someone can point to me the right place.

## Here is the error (edited):

TASK [openstack.kolla.baremetal : Enable ceph apt repository] **********************************************************************
fatal: [kao12.cec.edu]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: E:The repository 'https://download.ceph.com/debian-pacific jammy Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details., W:http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/11000/jammy/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details."}

## The previous ansible task was to updating /etc/apt/trusted.gpg (edited):

TASK [openstack.kolla.baremetal : Install ceph apt gpg key] *****************************************************************
ok: [kao12.cec.edu]

## The verbose error (edited)

<kao12.cec.edu> (1, b'\n{"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: W:https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details., E:The repository 'https://download.ceph.com/debian-pacific jammy Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/11000/jammy/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.", "invocation": {"module_args": {"repo": "deb https://download.ceph.com/debian-pacific/ jammy main", "filename": "ceph", "state": "present", "update_cache": true, "update_cache_retries": 5, "update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12, "install_python_apt": true, "validate_certs": true, "mode": null, "codename": null}}}\n', b"OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *\r\ndebug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/kolla/.ssh/known_hosts'\r\ndebug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/kolla/.ssh/known_hosts2'\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 228094\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\n")
<kao12.cec.edu> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/kolla/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/kolla/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 228094
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
fatal: [kao12.cec.edu]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"codename": null,
"filename": "ceph",
"install_python_apt": true,
"mode": null,
"repo": "deb https://download.ceph.com/debian-pacific/ jammy main",
"state": "present",
"update_cache": true,
"update_cache_retries": 5,
"update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12,
"validate_certs": true
}
},
"msg": "Failed to update apt cache: W:https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details., E:The repository 'https://download.ceph.com/debian-pacific jammy Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/11000/jammy/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details."
}

Comment: Have you retried? Sometimes online repos are not available for a short period of time, these things happen.

Comment: Thank you eblock.   Yes. I have for a few times over a week or two.  I noticed someone online mentioned it around 9/2022 about no ceph repository for ubuntu 22.04.  I got the workaround because I found out that repository requirement is tied to a zun setting that I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is more likely the ceph repository problem for ubuntu 22.04 and it happens to affect our environment, that is ubuntu 22.04 nodes, external ceph storage and zun enabled.

Also in our `/etc/kolla/globals.yml` this was enabled according to the document of kolla-ansible 16.1.0 external ceph.

```
zun_configure_for_cinder_ceph: "yes"
```

I figure we don't need that feature and turned it off.  Bootstrap-servers was successful.